# VBA:Excel how to copy including formatting and spacing

Tags: excel, vba

Right now, I'm doing this to copy a row from one sheet to another sheet and insert it at the end:

```
            Sheets("Monthly").Range("A1").EntireRow.Copy Destination:= _
            Sheets(Name).Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
```

But this doesn't copy any formatting/cell spacing. Is that possible to do in vba?

Comment: I don't think you're experiencing standard behaviour. Which Excel version do you work on?

Comment: I get "Copy method of Range class failed" :( @PortlandRunner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Copy` does copy the formatting. Maybe your formatting isn't what you think. I don't know what cell spacing means, but if it's column width, then `Copy` won't copy that. You'll have to set that explicitly, like

```
For i = 1 to rSrce.Cells.Count
    rDest.Cells(i).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = rSrce.Cells(1).EntireColumn.ColumnWidth
Next i
```

Comment: Ah, I thought the column width was part of the formatting, thanks

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure why it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Macro Recorder will give you the syntax for other formats.

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "General"
```

Or

```
.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Ex. of a way to solve it

```
Sub Copy()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

  ws.Range("A1").EntireColumn.Copy

    With ws.Range("G2").EntireColumn
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With

End Sub
```

There are a million ways to do this try

https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+copy+formatting+in+excel+with+vba&oq=how+to+co&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j69i57j69i59j69i60j0.2240j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I'm getting "Copy method of Range class failed" any idea?

Comment: At the end of my Range definition.

Comment: it looks like you found the answer but i edited mine just as future reference as another way.  All though more complex i guess.